# How can I set the row height in DataTable with scrolly option?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to have rows in my datatable of the same fixed height, but rowHeight option appears to have no effect.

I create a datatable like this:

HTML:

```
<table id="PositionsTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;height:70%;font-size:90%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>ActualPosition</th>
            <th>AccountIdent</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="PositionsBody">
```

Javascript:

```
   function CreatePositionsBodt(arr) {
        var existingbody = document.getElementById('PositionsBody');
        var table1 = document.getElementById('PositionsTable');
        var newBody = document.createElement('tbody');
        newBody.id = 'PositionsBody';
        var asArr = eval(arr);
        asArr.forEach(function (rowData) {
            var row = document.createElement('tr');

            rowData.forEach(function (cellData) {
                var cell = document.createElement('td');
                cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });

            newBody.appendChild(row);
        });
        table1.replaceChild(newBody, existingbody);
        existingbody.innerHTML = newBody.innerHTML;
    }
```

Then I use bootstrap:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PositionsTable').DataTable({
            scrollY: 500px,
            scroller: {
                rowHeight: 30
            },
            paging: false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "columns": [ { "width": "100px"},null,null]
        })
    });
```

Additional:

If I set scrollY: true then rowHeight does work BUT my table is NOT the size I want to to be...

Here is a JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/dh6sqesk/

Comment: can you provide any working demo to simulate it  ?

Comment: @TechnoCrat Example added see Fiddle

Comment: @TechnoCrat That works! If you make this into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

the height which you are trying to set static in style attribute of table tag that is impacting as per my analysis.

you can remove

```
width:100%;height:70%;font-size:90%
```

set it to

```
width:100%;font-size:90%
```

Comment: @ManInMoon i have added as answer as you told.